# Wordpress get_post_thumbnail_id not returning anything

Tags: php, wordpress

Why is it when I use `wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id));` I get nothing however when I `var_dump` the `post_id` I get `string(3) "652"` so I know that there is a ID

Without `(string)` it gives me `int(652)`

**Code:**

```
<?php
    $getPosts = new WP_Query(array('showposts' => 5, 'orderby' => 1));

     if($getPosts->have_posts()):
          $firstPost = true;

          while($getPosts->have_posts()):
                $getPosts->the_post();

              $cssClass = '';

              if($firstPost)
              {
                $cssClass = array('article','first-post');
                $postValue  = get_the_ID();
                $post_id    = (string)$postValue;
              }else{
                $cssClass = array('article');
              }
?>

<?php if($firstPost): ?>
    <?php $image =  wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id));?>
    <a href="<?php echo $image[0];?>">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) incorrectly as explained in the WordPress documentation:

> Returns an ordered array with values corresponding to the (0) url, (1)
>   width, (2) height, and (3) scale of an image attachment (or an icon
>   representing any attachment).

So it seems like your code should be as follows:

```
<?php if($firstPost): ?>
<?php
  $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id));
  $image = $image_attributes[0];
?>
<a href="<?php echo $image;?>">Test</a>
```

**EDIT:** Actually I am still unclear of your usage when you do this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $image;?>">Test</a>
```

You are setting the image URL in an `<a href></a>`? Why? Should it not be like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $image;?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the a link just to see if there was any data - with your code I am still getting blank.  Strange